# Changing web.config and session lifecyle

Tags: asp.net

If I change (and upload) the web.config of an ASP.NET site, do existing users surfing the site lose their sessions?

Also, does the IIS server need to be reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the session is in proc, then yes, they do loose their sessions.

If you are using a session server then no, they don't.

A new web.config would cause a restart of the site automaticlly, but should not require an IIS reset.

Comment: Thanks. What's involved in the restart of a site?

Comment: @dotnetdev - Sessions get unloaded, all `Session` state is lost, any caches are gone. Think of it as if you are restarting the machine - anything that wouldn't be ready in that situation, won't be after a restart (assuming the machine only hosts the website).

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the web.config file will cause the application to restart an it is equivalent to recycling the application pool. If you are using InProc session management, then yes, all user sessions will be lost. No, an IIS reset is not needed.